# Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance; selector doesn't exist?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I'm new to objective c, practically new to programming in general.

Anyway, in my simple program, I control-dragged my UITextField from the storyboard into my ViewController.m thinking it was a way to create a method to be invoked when the field was entered/tapped on. It wasn't long until I deleted the method.

When running the simulator, the keyboard would come up and the text field would already be focused on. If I tapped anywhere else on the screen, it resulted in a crash giving me the unrecognized selector error for the selector I already deleted.

There's nothing in my ViewController.h and the rest of the code seems fine. If I re-add the selector with no instructions, it behaves as intended and the keyboard resigns. My question is, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more helpful to have the output of the crash.  With that said I suspect your storyboard still has an outlet hooked up, referencing the function or outlet you created.  From your storyboard click on your textfield and then navigate to the connections inspector (view -> utilities -> connections inspector).  From there you should be able to see any connections you have made.  Click the x to get rid of it.

[image]

The connection inspector is the icon in the upper right with the right facing arrow inside of a circle.

Edit:

I realized you asked why this is happening and not how to fix it.  Unrecognized selector means just what it sounds like.  Your code, in this case the storyboard is trying to call a method or access a variable on an object that doesn't implement that method.  Normally the compiler catches these types of errors in your code but there are cases it can't catch, like the one your experiencing.  For example it is ok to assign an NSArray object to a variable declared as something else, say an NSString as follows

```
    id object = @[@"hello", @"world"];
    NSString *notAString = object;
    [notAString length];
```

Try running this and it will crash with a similar error because NSArray implement the length method, or in Objective-c speak, it doesn't respond to the selector "length".

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize IB kept a connection outside of the files I code in.

Answer (score 0):

Most typically it's this:

Select your UITextField in IB, go to the Connections inspector and remove the ghost connection to the removed method.